# Function sendCode is not working while sending message using twilio in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

I am using twilio for getting OTP for login through mobile number and this i am making in laravel framework ,I am making just user can log in through their registered number and when they put valid number they can get an OTP and after that they can login but, sendCode is not working.This is in logincontroller

```
public function OTPmobileLogin(Request $request){
 $OTPcount=User::select('id','name','phone','email')->where('phone',$req->phone)->first();
 if($OTPcount) {
 $token = Token::create([
 'user_id' => $user->id]);
 if ($token->sendCode()) {
```

Here using sendCode function which is located in a model named Token

```
session()->set("token_id", $token->id);
  session()->set("user_id", $user->id);
  session()->set("remember", $request->get('remember'));
  return redirect("code");}
  $token->delete();
  return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
  "Unable to send verification code"]);}
   return redirect()->back()
   ->withInputs()
   ->withErrors([
   $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed')]);}
```

In sendcode function returning  false , So what is i am doing wrong

```
public function sendCode(){
if (! $this->user) {
throw new \Exception("No user attached to this token.");}
if (! $this->code) {
$this->code = $this->generateCode();}
try {
app('twilio')->messages->create($this->user->getPhoneNumber(),
['from' => env('9873174535'), 'body' => "Your verification code is {$this->code}"]);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
return false;}
return true;}
public function generateCode($codeLength = 3)
{
$min = pow(10, $codeLength);
$max = $min * 10 - 1;
$code = mt_rand($min, $max);
return $code;}
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);}
public function isValid(){
return ! $this->isUsed() && ! $this->isExpired();}
public function isUsed(){
return $this->used;}
public function isExpired(){
return $this->created_at->diffInMinutes(Carbon::now()) > static::EXPIRATION_TIME;}
```

And in user model ,I am retrieving phone number

```
public function getPhoneNumber(){
  return $this->phone;}
```

Comment: I imagine that the Twilio library is throwing an error which you catch before returning false. Can you investigate the error to see what it says?

Comment: @philnash yes you are right and thank you for response, I did check all the other function ,running correctly only twilio is not sending msg.

Comment: Ok, so what is the error message in the exception? That should help you diagnose this.